# Why Im getting a "NoUserPoolError: Authentication Error" on CI while te all tests passed on locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

Im using cypress to test my react frontend. In locally all the tests pass without any issues. But it fails on CI showing this issue:

> NoUserPoolError: Authentication Error

Comment: Maybe your CI environment isn't set up to connect to your authentication endpoint correctly.

Comment: Yeah. I imported userpool ids to the cypress.json file. It fixed this issue. Thanks @ShafiqJetha.

Comment: I can turn my comment into an answer of you feel like it's appropriate.